# Share custom data with today extension by NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

this is my first post, so please be kind and constructive with me.

Im trying to share an array of custom objects with my Today Extension via NSuserDefauls.

I know that I can't put custom objects in NSUserdefaults so i coded them by NSKeyedArchiver - NSKeyedUnarchiver to transform them in NSData.

This is my custom class

```
    #import "Counter.h"

@implementation Counter

@dynamic city;
@dynamic address;
@dynamic event;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic time;
@dynamic counter;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;


- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{

    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.city forKey:@"city"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.address forKey:@"address"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.event forKey:@"event"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.date forKey:@"date"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.time forKey:@"time"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.counter forKey:@"counter"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.longitude forKey:@"longitude"];


}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self != nil )
    {
        self.city = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"city"];
        self.address = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"address"];
        self.event = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"event"];
        self.date = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"date"];
        self.time = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"time"];
        self.counter = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"counter"];
        self.latitude = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"latitude"];
        self.longitude = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"longitude"] ;

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

This is the coding function inside the app.

```
- (void)saveInUserDefault {

//Counter is my Custom class
//I'm Using MagicalRecord
NSArray *array = [Counter MR_findAllSortedBy:@"date" ascending:NO];

NSMutableArray *defaultMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:array.count];

NSUserDefaults *defaultArray = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.LorenzoLoRe.Everycount"];


for (Counter *cnt in array) {
    NSData *dataToDefault = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cnt];
    [defaultMutableArray addObject:dataToDefault];
}


[defaultArray setObject:defaultMutableArray forKey:@"counts"];
[defaultArray synchronize];
}
```

At this point looking at the log, data seems to be write in NSUserDefaults

And here i try to retrive the data in the Extension

```
-

 (void)takeLastCounts {

    NSUserDefaults *defaultArray = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.company.product"];
    [defaultArray synchronize];

    NSArray  *dummyArray = [defaultArray arrayForKey:@"counts"];;
    NSMutableArray *arrayFromDefault= NULL;
    Counter *cter = nil;


   for (NSData *data in dummyArray) {
       cter = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
       [arrayFromDefault addObject:cter];
    }

    self.cnt_1 = arrayFromDefault[0];
    self.cnt_2 = arrayFromDefault[1];

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    self.eventLabel.text = self.cnt_1.event;
    self.dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:self.cnt_1.date];
    self.counterLabel.text = self.cnt_1.counter.stringValue;
    self.timeLabel.text = self.cnt_1.time;

}
```

When i try to execute the Extension, theres no errors but just empty Arrays.
In particular `NSArray  *dummyArray = [defaultArray arrayForKey:@"counts"];` seems to be empty, so somewhere the data don't flows.

What I'm doing wrong??

Any kind of tips will be ver appreciate.

Comment: What is the type of your "counter" property ? Is it NSNumber ? Could it be that U use a primitive type but forget to wrap it in object before saving ?

Comment: these are the property:`@interface Counter : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * event;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate   * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString   * time;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * counter;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@end`

Comment: do you have provisioning profile with "group.company.product" gruop name entitilement added with your app and extension and also "group.company.product" is mentioned in your appgroup for both.

Comment: Yes. I have an entitlement file both for the app and the extension , and all of them has the same string "group.company.product".  I added it in "app groups"(under capabilities ). Inside the entitlement i have "array" as data type. I tried to do some experiments changing the data type or adding some subtype ...but when i switch from array type Xcode crush.